# Set button to text to pending while uploading file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, onclick

I am creating a simple mvc application where the user uploads a document and clicks submit on a form to upload the file. I am trying to change the 'Upload' text to 'Pending' while the computer is uploading the document to the database (it takes five minutes).

I have something like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Upload" onclick="this.disabled = true; value = 'Pending';" />
```

which changes the text of the 'Upload' button to 'Pending'. However, if the user clicks the 'Upload' button when the file has not been submitted the text of the 'Upload' button still changes to 'Pending', even though the computer is not uploading the document to the database.

Is there someway I can do this - with Javascript or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 onclick="this.disabled = true; this.value= 'Pending';"
```

Although from server side change **text** of this one after file has been uploaded

***And if you want to check file has a file or not***

```
 onclick="if($('#fileupload').val()!=''){this.disabled = true; this.value= 'Pending';}else{$('#fileupload').focus();}"
```

Comment: OP wanted it on submit, not just on button click. This also does nothing different to what OP currently has and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BeatAlex what onclick will do?

Comment: OP doesn't want to use onclick, because it will do it whether or not the form has a file uploading. So they want to know when the form has been submitted rather than just on button click.

Comment: Hello man check my second code if he want to validate he can validate through onclick also and why you have down voted? @BeatAlex

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'true').val('Pending');
});
```

Or you can do:

```
$('input'[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
  if ($('#upload').val != "") //if the input isn't empty (assuming id is called #upload)
  {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'true').val('Pending');
    $('form').submit();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

So the submit button will only be changed to disabled and change value when then form is submitted, rather than just when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a custom 'button'

merely a pretty div, and attach a javascript function to its 'onclick' event.

next, in the javascript function you can either set the text of that div to "uploading" and 
do a

```
document.forms.yourFormName.submit();
```

and get rid of your input button,

or make that button's visibility to "hidden"
and in the javascript use jQuery to find the button and do a

```
.toggle("click");
```